# \n is not working while \t works as expected

Tags: matlab, printf, octave

I have a very long script with a lot of `plot` functions and related `legend` functions but these `legend` functions use 1, 2, 3 or 4 to locate legends on corners (as it was in older versions). However now I need to change them with name/value pairs. To do so, I wrote down a script to convert them. I want to copy code into text file and converted code will be on another text file so I can recopy it to my .m files. Here my code is;

```
fid=fopen('drawFigure.txt','r');
fid2=fopen('drawFigure2.txt','w');
codeLine=fgetl(fid);
while(codeLine ~= -1)
  legAv=strfind(codeLine,'legend');
  if (~isempty(legAv))

    loc3=strfind(codeLine,'3');
    loc2=strfind(codeLine,'2');

    if(~isempty(loc3))
    loc=loc3;
    elseif(~isempty(loc2))
    loc=loc2;
    end
  %here I check the next indice of codeLine to make sure I will change location factor
    if(codeLine(loc+1)==')')
      codeLine(loc)=[];
      str1=codeLine(1:loc-1);
      str2=codeLine(loc:length(codeLine));
      mystr="'location','northeast'";
      codeLine=strcat(str1,mystr,str2);

    endif

  endif



  fprintf(fid2,'%s\n',codeLine);


  codeLine=fgetl(fid);

endwhile
 fclose(fid2);
 fclose(fid);`
```

In this code, If I wrote `\t`, it would be working but `\n` is not working. Also, tried to get help from a software engineer friend but he couldn’t figure out the reason.

Comment: “how to color my example code” Syntax highlighting is applied automatically if the right language tag is applied. You can also explicitly add the language name after the code fence (three backticks).

Comment: By the way, the most likely explanation for what you’re seeing is that you’re on Windows and you write text to a binary file. Try opening the file with `"wt"` instead of `"w"`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo okay will try this also, thanks

Comment: btw, you are doing a lot of things in this code which look "weird" for octave. E.g., you do not need parentheses around the test that follows an `if` or a `while` keyword (i.e. you can just say `while codeLine ~= 1` and `if ~isempty( legAv )`. Also, you can say `codeLine(loc:end)` instead of `codeLine(loc:length(codeLine))`. Also this isn't a self-contained example, so I can't tell if your `loc` variable is meant to be defined elsewhere; but if not, then you have a logical error in your code. Obvs we would be able to help you better if your code was a standalone example we can debug ourselves.

Comment: Also, I can't help feeling this smells of XY problem. What is it exactly you're trying to do? Do you have a toy example of the kind of script you're trying to modify?

Comment: well, I can say this is my X problem. I just want to modify an old script file to work on new versions of MatLab and/or Octave. I dont have an example of it but what I can say is it consists of 20k lines with a lot of plot commands followed by legend commands. Yeah, the code I write above now works without any problem on my personal computer but not on the office's computer. Now I will try to understand what causes this on monday. Looks like it is an OS problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo this worked in office too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your information, I am guessing that you are opening your file using Windows notepad. If this is the case, newlines (`\n`) are not shown unless preceeded by a cariage return (`\r`). This means that you should change:

```
fprintf(fid2,'%s\n',codeLine);
```

to

```
fprintf(fid2,'%s\r\n',codeLine);
```

or alternatively, use a basic text editor with more support such as Notepad++ for Windows.

Comment: I will definitely try this, let me accept your answer when i tried and see it worked. I am using windows notepad.

Comment: I do not agree with this solution. The right approach is to open the file for writing in text mode, as I said in a comment to the question. Open mode should be `"wt"`, which will use the right line breaks in any platform.